# Efficiently sorting by LOWER in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

This wonderful [blog posts](https://medium.com/google-cloud/bigquery-performance-tips-searching-for-text-8x-faster-f9314927b8d2) talks about the inefficiencies of using `LOWER()` in where clauses and more efficient ways to search text. Is there a similar way to do that in the `ORDER BY` clause? For example:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
ORDER BY LOWER(first_name)
```

What would be the most efficient way to sort by the lowercased-text of the field name, such as would be done in Google Sheets or Excel when sorting by a column?

Comment: important note from respective SO post - `Note from the team: Stay tuned! Very soon BigQuery will turn this advice irrelevant.` did you see it? :o)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yea, I noticed that as well. Not sure when that would be implemented though. I check their release docs every day.

Comment: Some things are already faster--have you tried the queries from the blog post? I don't think we will update the release notes until we fix all known issues, but the first couple of queries take only ~4 or 5 seconds instead of 10s of seconds. I don't think that ORDER BY LOWER(...) should be slow in any case.

Comment: amazing blog/post; amazing team!!! :o)

Comment: exactly - I have to blog about that now :)

Answer (score 1):

RegExp approach as in referenced blog will not work / applicable here (for `ORDER BY` ) because respective needed functionality is not supported by [`re2`](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) library which is used for BigQuery regular expression support

Specifically - re2 does not support changing case in regex replace

if it would be supported - you could use something like

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(first_name, r'.*', r'\L\0') <-- just mockup - does not work with BigQuery
```

Here `\L` - converts all subsequent tokens into their respective lowercase equivalences
and  `\0` (this is supported by BQ) matches entire pattern so the the whole `first_name` column would be replaced with respective lowercased version

See example [`here`](https://regex101.com/r/7iVUvF/1)

But - again - `\L` is not supported by BigQuery / re2